# How to attach one event listener to many objects?

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I'm caching jQuery selectors onto objects:

```
var a = {x:1};
var b = {y:2};

a.$btn = $('<div/>').addClass('button').appendTo('body').find('.button');
b.$btn = $('<div/>').addClass('button').appendTo('body').find('.button');

$('.button').on('click', function(e){ doSomething(e); });
```

Is it possible to use a single event listener and change a.x or b.y?

Edit: I'm currently adding events for each object created, which works but seems inefficient:

```
a.$btn.on('click', function(e) { doSomething.call(this,e); }.bind(this));
```

Edit 2: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz8hvkvw/5/)

Comment: slightly confused, does `thing.addEventListener("whateverevent", function() { a.x = 4; b.x = 100; });` not work? They're in scope for the function, so that'd work without errors?

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans - Added an edit the same time you commented, it may help expand on my initial question.

Comment: How do you want to change `a.x` or `b.y`? I would imagine something like an event handler for clicking the `button` class would work. Along with a way to tell which button you are clicking (such as an `id`).

Comment: Your question is not clear about what exactly is the problem. Do you want to modify `a.x` when `a.$btn` is clicked and `b.y` when `b.$btn`  is clicked?

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek - I'm not using DOM id's, I'm caching selectors for certain elements; when an events triggers I need to change the relevant object in memory and it's properties.

Comment: @Kirill Slatin - Yes, I want to change object properties as you wrote and wondered if there's a way to use one listener instead of a listener for each object instance.

Comment: Check out event delegation - https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Then switch the hierarchy: created button should have a reference to the object. For example, `a.$btn.object = a` on creation. Then in one handler you can use, `doSomething.call(e.target.object, e);`

Comment: @user2182349 - event delegation is for the DOM; my objects live in memory which I'm augmenting with jQuery selectors.

Comment: @Data, you end up adding your elements to DOM in anyway, by `appendTo('body'). So, yes, you can use event delegation to assign your handler to all your buttons. But still ED doesn't solve the problem of context for handler

Comment: @Kirill Slatin - can you expand on your object reference comment with an answer, so I can mark it as answered, thanks.

Comment: `function(e) { doSomething.call(this,e); }.bind(this)` seems weird. Have you considered `$.proxy()`? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: @Sukima. do you want to state that `$.proxy()` is not implemented via `bind()`? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a handler to each created button or use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as stated by @user2182349.

However, event delegation doesn't solve the problem of context for a single handler. I see two solutions.

**Simple and straightforward solution:**

Switch the hierarchy: created button should have a reference to the object. For example:

```
a.$btn = $('<div/>').addClass('button').appendTo('body').find('.button');
a.$btn.object = a;
$('.button').on('click', function(e){ doSomething.call(e.target.object, e); });
```

**There is another more complicated solution.** Which prevents modification of your object structure. If you have a pool of your created objects you can iterate it and locate the parent by the button.

```
var pool = [a, b];
function findObject(button){
    for (var obj in pool){
        if(obj.$btn === button){
            return obj;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function handler(e){
    var obj = findObject(e.target);
    if(obj){
         doSomething.call(obj, e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Regarding the JSFiddle from the updated OP:

```
var a = b = Object.create(null);
a.x = 1;
b.y = 2;
```

just creates 1 (one!) object and two variables that reference it. As a result you end up with a single object with two properties: `x` and `y`.
Take a look at updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mz8hvkvw/7/)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm confused by a.$btn.object = a, isn't that a self-reference? It would be var a = {}; a.x = 1; a.$btn = $('<div/>')...

Comment: This is called circular reference, not self-reference `a->btn->a`. Yes, but I don't know why you need a reference to button in your business object. I would just create a button and insert a reference to BO. `$btn.object = a`. I don't know your entire process, wether you need a reference to button later, that's why I left what wrote as it is. Hence a circular ref

Comment: I've always done it as objects first (as you define them BO's) and then augmenting them with jQuery selectors; your answer has totally changed my thinking and I have a lot of refactoring to do ;( Would it be possible for you to post a simple jsfiddle, so I have a solid foundation from which to build. Thanks for your help Kirill, it's sincerely much appreciated; I'll mark your answer once I've done some testing.

Comment: You did a good job breaking down your problem into a simple example code. So the question is not littered with custom logic of app that you're writing. But from an example code it is hard to follow the logic enough to build a fiddle that would help you. If you post a fiddle that demonstrates your current problems as they are, i will gladly update it according to this thread. BTW why are you afraid of circular references? Are you going to serialize your objects in JSON? Property that has a value of a DOM element or $ object will still make it a hassle

Comment: because they are not intended to be serialized and contain circular refs :)

Comment: I've added a link to a jsfiddle in the OP (Edit #2); hope it works for you, I've never written a fiddle before.

Comment: just wanted to add that I'm really excited to see if you can fix my fiddle. My whole code is based on this object augmentation technique, so if you can show me the 'proper' way, I'd be most grateful. I always wondered why chrome made my PC fan whir away, polluting memory with too much stuff but I don't get memory leaks using the timeline heap after GC, i.e. there's no 'stair-stepping'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78979/discussion-between-kirill-slatin-and-data).

Answer (score 0):

if you have a parent element for all your other objects, you can do it this way:

```
$('#parent').on('click', '.elemClass1 .elemClass2 .elemClass3',function(e){ doSomething(e); });
```

if it doesn't work, try it separating by commas `'.elemClass1, .elemClass2, .elemClass3'`

Comment: How would I then change an object property in memory, e.g. var obj = { a : 1, b: 2}; depending which class was invoked? btw, your code would need 'e.stopPropagation()' to stop invocation of other elements.

Comment: @Mollo. this would work when parent is a DOM object. We are searching for a way to locate a parent which is not a DOM element

Comment: Uhmm, I didn't read you cannot have a DOM object as a parent ... It gets a little more dificult now